# WSL2 / wslg Windows Start menu app - where is the $PATH env pulled from?

Tags: environment-variables, start-menu, windows-11, wsl2, rstudio

I've compiled the latest gnu compiler (11.2) on Ubuntu 20.04.
In my~/.bashrc , the directory I have gcc/g++ installed in is pathed.

Now, I have compiled R in wsl2 using the gcc 11.2 compiler. Then I've installed Rstudio (an IDE for the R statistical language). Once installed, I can run Rstudio which uses my compiled R from the windows 11 start menu. Nice!

However, R itself, when invoked via Rstudio launched from the Win11 start menu, is not getting the paths I set in ~/.bashrc.

That means, there is no compiler pathed within the R console environment, those paths are in my .bashrc. When you compile packages within R, it uses the same flags that were used to build R itself. So without gcc11.2 in the R console environment, R can't invoke gcc 11.2 to compile any packages! That's a huge problem.
I've set default user in /etc/wsl.conf as me, and if I check the system environment from the R console, I can see that when launched from the Win11 start menu, I'm being set correctly as the user.

If I open a system terminal within Rstudio, it also runs as my user account, but it processes ~/.bashrc and all is peachy. BUT importantly, the terminal is not running the same environment as the R console.

It's obvious that the R console seems to not be getting a post-bashrc environment when executed from the Win11 start menu. When Rstudio is launched from the win11 start menu, it's getting a bare bones environment.

If I start WSL.EXE which defaults to my user account, and then launch Rstudio from there, the R console gets the right paths. Yay. Compiling packages works. So I could just do that I guess.... BUT I want it to be neat, and just have it all work from the start menu.

So, where does a linux app that is launched from the Win11 start menu get it's environment variables from? And how can I append, or just use the $PATH from my ~/.bashrc?

Many thanks
K

Answer (score 2):

This appears somewhat similar (but not identical) to the situation I mention in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66055665/11810933), just that instead of `wsl.exe`, we're now dealing with `wslg.exe`.

To summarize, when you launch a Linux GUI app through the Start menu in Windows, it uses a shortcut that calls the app via:

```
wslg.exe ~ -d <distroname> <app> <arguments>
```

As with the `wsl.exe` command, `wslg.exe` starts the shell (and it *does* start the shell first) as a non-login, non-interactive shell.  This means that `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` are not processed when launching with the Start menu shortcuts.

The solution is similar -- Edit the shortcut by:

- Right-clicking the Linux app in the Start menu
- Select *Open File Location*
- Right-click the corresponding shortcut in the ... -> *Start Menu* -> *Programs* ->  folder.
- Select *Properties*
- Change the *Target* from:

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d <distroname> <app> <arguments>
  ```

  to ...

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d <distroname> bash -ilc <app> <arguments>
  ```

Side-note #1:  Technically it's probably better to put your `PATH` adjustment in `~/.bash_profile` and specify `bash -lc` instead of `bash -ilc`.  That would allow you to (in the future, if desired) execute *interactive* commands in your `~/.bashrc`.  For instance, I start `keychain` (an `ssh-agent` manager) in my interactive sessions, and it unlocks a specified SSH key via password prompt.  That type of interactive command would prevent `wslg.exe` from launching, since it doesn't launch a terminal/interactive session.

If you ever *do* add something interactive to your `~/.bashrc`, it will break this Start Menu adjustment, and you may not remember why without additional research.  Better to "get it right" now and prevent potential future problems.

Side-note #2 (for my own future reference and anyone experienced with the `wsl.exe` command) -- The `wslg.exe` command (oddly) does *not* appear to support the `-e` flag to launch directly into a shell.  This means that you will actually be executing the shell twice in this case -- The first execution will be `wslg.exe` launching your default shell (again, as a non-login, non-interactive shell), then your default shell (likely bash) will turn around and launch another `bash` as an interactive login shell.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds I had a feeling that could be done. Your [[ C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d <distroname> bash -ilc <app> <arguments> ]] works of course. I'd really love an out-of-the-box solution for this so that each link doesn't have to be updated. C'est la vie!